# '05 Honda CR-V multiplexer wiring issue?

Tags: honda, electrical, o2-sensor, crv

Having issues with the door lock relay decided to replace the multiplexer with one from the salvage yard. Unfortunately this did NOT fix the issue and introduced a new issue. It cause the engine light to come on. Checking the code shows a bad heating element for the oxygen sensor.

I switch back the old multiplexer unit and cleared the code but it came right back again. I checked the F4 fuse on the multiplex unit and the fuse under the hood. Both are OK.

Does anyone know what plug on the multiplex unit has the wiring for the oxygen sensor? I wonder if disconnecting the recounting the plug has caused a broker wire?

I'm going to start checking the oxygen sensor but the coincidence seems unlikely.

Thanks!

Matt

UPDATE:
I found a post for clearing the error code on an '08 CR-V where after clearing the code, you run the engine at 3000 RPM until it reaches operating temp. That process cleared the code, so far it has no come back on. Here's a link (if allowed) to the process. https://www.crvownersclub.com/threads/2008-crv-code-po135.226464/

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! To my knowledge, the multiplexer has nothing to do with the heater circuit on the O2 sensors. I'm pretty sure what you're actually seeing is a coincidence, even as unlikely as it seems.

Comment: I think the first thing to do is unplug the o2 sensor and check the resistance of the o2 sensor heater and also check if there is 12v on the heater pins of the connector.

Comment: @Paulster2, I think you are right, just odd it came on after swapping out the multiplexer.

Comment: @HandyHowie, I did just that and tested of power at the O2 sensor and also tested the resistance. Best I could tell they were OK.